# I m new programmer in android I got Gson Error

Tags: android, json

```
public class OrderBook implements Serializable{

    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @SerializedName("AppOrdID")
    @Expose
    private String appOrdID;
    @SerializedName("ClientID")
    @Expose
    private String clientID;
    @SerializedName("ExchangeSegment")
    @Expose
    private Integer exchangeSegment;
    @SerializedName("InstrumentID")
    @Expose
    private String instrumentID;
    @SerializedName("TradeSymbol")
    @Expose
    private String tradeSymbol;
    @SerializedName("OrderStatus")
    @Expose
    private Integer orderStatus;
    @SerializedName("OrderSide")
    @Expose
    private Integer orderSide;
    @SerializedName("OrderQuantity")
    @Expose
    private Integer orderQuantity;
    @SerializedName("OrderPrice")
    @Expose
    private Double orderPrice;
    @SerializedName("ProductType")
    @Expose
    private Integer productType;
    @SerializedName("TradedQuantity")
    @Expose
    private Integer tradedQuantity;
    @SerializedName("RemainingQuantity")
    @Expose
    private Integer remainingQuantity;
    @SerializedName("OrderType")
    @Expose
    private Integer orderType;
    @SerializedName("TimeInForce")
    @Expose
    private Integer timeInForce;
    @SerializedName("TriggerPrice")
    @Expose
    private Integer triggerPrice;
    @SerializedName("DisclosedQuantity")
    @Expose
    private Integer disclosedQuantity;
    @SerializedName("AveragePrice")
    @Expose
    private Integer averagePrice;
    @SerializedName("ExpiryDate")
    @Expose
    private String expiryDate;
    @SerializedName("OrderTime")
    @Expose
    private String orderTime;
    @SerializedName("TradeTime")
    @Expose
    private String tradeTime;
    @SerializedName("UpdateTime")
    @Expose
    private String updateTime;
    @SerializedName("ExchangeOrderID")
    @Expose
    private String exchangeOrderID;
    @SerializedName("ExchangeOrderUpdateTime")
    @Expose
    private String exchangeOrderUpdateTime;
    @SerializedName("UserID")
    @Expose
    private String userID;
    @SerializedName("RejectReason")
    @Expose
    private String rejectReason;
    @SerializedName("RequestID")
    @Expose
    private String requestID;

    // new  add
    @SerializedName("ScripName")
    @Expose
    private String scripName;
    @SerializedName("OrderValidityDate")
    @Expose
    private String orderValidityDate;
    @SerializedName("MarketProtection")
    @Expose
    private String marketProtection;
    @SerializedName("CancelledQuantity")
    @Expose
    private String cancelledQuantity;
    @SerializedName("TickSize")
    @Expose
    private String tickSize;
    @SerializedName("DecimalPrecision")
    @Expose
    private String decimalPrecision;
    @SerializedName("Multiplier")
    @Expose
    private String multiplier;
    @SerializedName("NoMarketProtection")
    @Expose
    private String noMarketProtection;
    @SerializedName("DefaultMarketProtection")
    @Expose
    private String defaultMarketProtection;
    @SerializedName("ReferenceOrdID")
    @Expose
    private String referenceOrdID;
    @SerializedName("COPercentage")
    @Expose
    private String coPercentage;
    @SerializedName("InstrumentName")
    @Expose
    private String instrumentName;
    @SerializedName("ExpSsbDate")
    @Expose
    private String expSsbDate;
    @SerializedName("discQtyPerc")
    @Expose
    private String discQtyPerc;
    @SerializedName("Minqty")
    @Expose
    private String minqty;
    @SerializedName("BrokerClient")
    @Expose
    private String brokerClient;
    @SerializedName("PriceNum")
    @Expose
    private String priceNum;
    @SerializedName("GenNum")
    @Expose
    private String genNum;
    @SerializedName("PriceDenum")
    @Expose
    private String priceDenum;
    @SerializedName("GenDenum")
    @Expose
    private String genDenum;
    @SerializedName("Series")
    @Expose
    private String series;
    @SerializedName("OrderGenerationType")
    @Expose
    private String orderGenerationType;
    @SerializedName("SIPIndicator")
    @Expose
    private String sipIndicator;
    @SerializedName("OrderSource")
    @Expose
    private String orderSource;
    @SerializedName("Remarks")
    @Expose
    private String remarks;
    @SerializedName("MarketProPercentage")
    @Expose
    private String marketProPercentage;
    @SerializedName("ReportType")
    @Expose
    private String reportType;
    @SerializedName("RefLmtPrice")
    @Expose
    private String refLmtPrice;



    public String getAppOrdID() {
        return appOrdID;
    }

    public void setAppOrdID(String appOrdID) {
        this.appOrdID = appOrdID;
    }

    public String getClientID() {
        return clientID;
    }

    public void setClientID(String clientID) {
        this.clientID = clientID;
    }

    public Integer getExchangeSegment() {
        return exchangeSegment;
    }

    public void setExchangeSegment(Integer exchangeSegment) {
        this.exchangeSegment = exchangeSegment;
    }

    public String getInstrumentID() {
        return instrumentID;
    }

    public void setInstrumentID(String instrumentID) {
        this.instrumentID = instrumentID;
    }

    public String getTradeSymbol() {
        return tradeSymbol;
    }

    public void setTradeSymbol(String tradeSymbol) {
        this.tradeSymbol = tradeSymbol;
    }

    public Integer getOrderStatus() {
        return orderStatus;
    }

    public void setOrderStatus(Integer orderStatus) {
        this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
    }

    public Integer getOrderSide() {
        return orderSide;
    }

    public void setOrderSide(Integer orderSide) {
        this.orderSide = orderSide;
    }

    public Integer getOrderQuantity() {
        return orderQuantity;
    }

    public void setOrderQuantity(Integer orderQuantity) {
        this.orderQuantity = orderQuantity;
    }

    public Double getOrderPrice() {
        return orderPrice;
    }

    public void setOrderPrice(Double orderPrice) {
        this.orderPrice = orderPrice;
    }

    public Integer getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(Integer productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

    public Integer getTradedQuantity() {
        return tradedQuantity;
    }

    public void setTradedQuantity(Integer tradedQuantity) {
        this.tradedQuantity = tradedQuantity;
    }

    public Integer getRemainingQuantity() {
        return remainingQuantity;
    }

    public void setRemainingQuantity(Integer remainingQuantity) {
        this.remainingQuantity = remainingQuantity;
    }

    public Integer getOrderType() {
        return orderType;
    }

    public void setOrderType(Integer orderType) {
        this.orderType = orderType;
    }

    public Integer getTimeInForce() {
        return timeInForce;
    }

    public void setTimeInForce(Integer timeInForce) {
        this.timeInForce = timeInForce;
    }

    public Integer getTriggerPrice() {
        return triggerPrice;
    }

    public void setTriggerPrice(Integer triggerPrice) {
        this.triggerPrice = triggerPrice;
    }

    public Integer getDisclosedQuantity() {
        return disclosedQuantity;
    }

    public void setDisclosedQuantity(Integer disclosedQuantity) {
        this.disclosedQuantity = disclosedQuantity;
    }

    public Integer getAveragePrice() {
        return averagePrice;
    }

    public void setAveragePrice(Integer averagePrice) {
        this.averagePrice = averagePrice;
    }

    public String getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(String expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }

    public String getOrderTime() {
        return orderTime;
    }

    public void setOrderTime(String orderTime) {
        this.orderTime = orderTime;
    }

    public String getTradeTime() {
        return tradeTime;
    }

    public void setTradeTime(String tradeTime) {
        this.tradeTime = tradeTime;
    }

    public String getUpdateTime() {
        return updateTime;
    }

    public void setUpdateTime(String updateTime) {
        this.updateTime = updateTime;
    }

    public String getExchangeOrderID() {
        return exchangeOrderID;
    }

    public void setExchangeOrderID(String exchangeOrderID) {
        this.exchangeOrderID = exchangeOrderID;
    }

    public String getExchangeOrderUpdateTime() {
        return exchangeOrderUpdateTime;
    }

    public void setExchangeOrderUpdateTime(String exchangeOrderUpdateTime) {
        this.exchangeOrderUpdateTime = exchangeOrderUpdateTime;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getRejectReason() {
        return rejectReason;
    }

    public void setRejectReason(String rejectReason) {
        this.rejectReason = rejectReason;
    }

    public String getRequestID() {
        return requestID;
    }

    public void setRequestID(String requestID) {
        this.requestID = requestID;
    }

    public String getScripName() {
        return scripName;
    }

    public void setScripName(String scripName) {
        this.scripName = scripName;
    }

    public String getOrderValidityDate() {
        return orderValidityDate;
    }

    public void setOrderValidityDate(String orderValidityDate) {
        this.orderValidityDate = orderValidityDate;
    }

    public String getMarketProtection() {
        return marketProtection;
    }

    public void setMarketProtection(String marketProtection) {
        this.marketProtection = marketProtection;
    }

    public String getCancelledQuantity() {
        return cancelledQuantity;
    }

    public void setCancelledQuantity(String cancelledQuantity) {
        this.cancelledQuantity = cancelledQuantity;
    }

    public String getTickSize() {
        return tickSize;
    }

    public void setTickSize(String tickSize) {
        this.tickSize = tickSize;
    }

    public String getDecimalPrecision() {
        return decimalPrecision;
    }

    public void setDecimalPrecision(String decimalPrecision) {
        this.decimalPrecision = decimalPrecision;
    }

    public String getMultiplier() {
        return multiplier;
    }

    public void setMultiplier(String multiplier) {
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
    }

    public String getNoMarketProtection() {
        return noMarketProtection;
    }

    public void setNoMarketProtection(String noMarketProtection) {
        this.noMarketProtection = noMarketProtection;
    }

    public String getDefaultMarketProtection() {
        return defaultMarketProtection;
    }

    public void setDefaultMarketProtection(String defaultMarketProtection) {
        this.defaultMarketProtection = defaultMarketProtection;
    }

    /*public String getSyomOrderID() {
        return syomOrderID;
    }

    public void setSyomOrderID(String syomOrderID) {
        this.syomOrderID = syomOrderID;
    }*/

    public String getReferenceOrdID() {
        return referenceOrdID;
    }

    public void setReferenceOrdID(String referenceOrdID) {
        this.referenceOrdID = referenceOrdID;
    }

    public String getCoPercentage() {
        return coPercentage;
    }

    public void setCoPercentage(String coPercentage) {
        this.coPercentage = coPercentage;
    }

    public String getInstrumentName() {
        return instrumentName;
    }

    public void setInstrumentName(String instrumentName) {
        this.instrumentName = instrumentName;
    }

    public String getExpSsbDate() {
        return expSsbDate;
    }

    public void setExpSsbDate(String expSsbDate) {
        this.expSsbDate = expSsbDate;
    }

    public String getDiscQtyPerc() {
        return discQtyPerc;
    }

    public void setDiscQtyPerc(String discQtyPerc) {
        this.discQtyPerc = discQtyPerc;
    }

    public String getMinqty() {
        return minqty;
    }

    public void setMinqty(String minqty) {
        this.minqty = minqty;
    }

    public String getBrokerClient() {
        return brokerClient;
    }

    public void setBrokerClient(String brokerClient) {
        this.brokerClient = brokerClient;
    }

    public String getPriceNum() {
        return priceNum;
    }

    public void setPriceNum(String priceNum) {
        this.priceNum = priceNum;
    }

    public String getGenNum() {
        return genNum;
    }

    public void setGenNum(String genNum) {
        this.genNum = genNum;
    }

    public String getPriceDenum() {
        return priceDenum;
    }

    public void setPriceDenum(String priceDenum) {
        this.priceDenum = priceDenum;
    }

    public String getGenDenum() {
        return genDenum;
    }

    public void setGenDenum(String genDenum) {
        this.genDenum = genDenum;
    }

    public String getSeries() {
        return series;
    }

    public void setSeries(String series) {
        this.series = series;
    }

    public String getOrderGenerationType() {
        return orderGenerationType;
    }

    public void setOrderGenerationType(String orderGenerationType) {
        this.orderGenerationType = orderGenerationType;
    }

    public String getSipIndicator() {
        return sipIndicator;
    }

    public void setSipIndicator(String sipIndicator) {
        this.sipIndicator = sipIndicator;
    }

    public String getOrderSource() {
        return orderSource;
    }

    public void setOrderSource(String orderSource) {
        this.orderSource = orderSource;
    }

    public String getRemarks() {
        return remarks;
    }

    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }

    public String getMarketProPercentage() {
        return marketProPercentage;
    }

    public void setMarketProPercentage(String marketProPercentage) {
        this.marketProPercentage = marketProPercentage;
    }

    public String getReportType() {
        return reportType;
    }

    public void setReportType(String reportType) {
        this.reportType = reportType;
    }

    public String getRefLmtPrice() {
        return refLmtPrice;
    }

    public void setRefLmtPrice(String refLmtPrice) {
        this.refLmtPrice = refLmtPrice;
    }
}
```

I get and error Please help Me

> > {serializeNulls:falsefactories:[Factory[typeHierarchy=com.google.gson.JsonElement,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25@250463], com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter$1@eab3860, com.google.gson.internal.Excluder@4547119, Factory[type=java.lang.String,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13@4bff5de], Factory[type=java.lang.Integer+int,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7@a5983bf], Factory[type=java.lang.Boolean+boolean,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$3@2fb7a8c], Factory[type=java.lang.Byte+byte,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$5@8b205d5], Factory[type=java.lang.Short+short,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$6@95191ea], Factory[type=java.lang.Long+long,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$8@72c9cdb], Factory[type=java.lang.Double+double,adapter=com.google.gson.Gson$3@22bb378], Factory[type=java.lang.Float+float,adapter=com.google.gson.Gson$4@41a2a51], Factory[type=java.lang.Number,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11@3aee2b6], Factory[type=java.lang.Character+char,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$12@94e2bb7], Factory[type=java.lang.StringBuilder,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16@e248f24], Factory[type=java.lang.StringBuffer,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$17@3061a8d], Factory[type=java.math.BigDecimal,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$14@bbe7442], Factory[type=java.math.BigInteger,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$15@48fcc53], Factory[type=java.net.URL,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$18@cad7990], Factory[type=java.net.URI,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$19@646d289], Factory[type=java.util.UUID,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$21@f43928e], Factory[type=java.util.Locale,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$24@e40daaf], Factory[typeHierarchy=java.net.InetAddress,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$20@6989ebc], Factory[type=java.util.BitSet,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$2@c10e45], com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter$1@2ea499a, Factory[type=java.util.Calendar+java.util.GregorianCalendar,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$23@74a72cb], com.google.gson.internal.bind.TimeTypeAdapter$1@daeeaa8, com.google.gson.internal.bind.SqlDateTypeAdapter$1@4e949c1, com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$22@8136566, com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter$1@c0b70a7, Factory[type=java.lang.Class,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1@55c0954], com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory@dffc0fd, com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory@36071f2, com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonAdapterAnnotationTypeAdapterFactory@5f47043, com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$26@a1a66c0, com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory@10c6ff9],instanceCreators:{}}

Comment: I guess your OrderBook Class has some wrong datatypes set with reference to your json response.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a plugin to easily create POJO class for your json response.Follow the steps below, hope this could help you

1. Install GsonFormat plugin
2. Generate a new class.
3. in this new class, inside the body of the class, right click.
4. in the menu that opens choose Generate.
5. in the new menu that open choose GsonFormat.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Codes{
    public String code;
    public String price;
}

class Result
{
ArrayList<Codes> codes = new ArrayList();

// create getter setter of 'codes' variable.
```

}

Comment: please explain how this addresses the errors in the question.

Comment: Actually in Json "codes" is a parameter you can give any name to the class but we need to user the same parameter name as variable in the class and after "codes" we have square bracket means array of data so we use arraylist to parse the array data from JSON